# My network applet thingy has dissapeared

Tags: gnome, networking

In `System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications` I have `nm-applet --sm-disable` Ticked.

I don't know why its not showing up after boot.

Comment: possibly related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/637202

Answer (score 3):

I had to right click the top bar, choose `Add to panel` and add the `Notification area`

Answer (score 1):

Try opening a terminal and type

```
killall nm-applet
nm-applet &
```

If that still doesn't work, post the results of doing this into your question.